# Matplotlib not displaying all values

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to display the following values in the form of a bar chart. However, I am only getting one value displayed (619,1). Below is the code which I used in an attempt to plot the below graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('ggplot')
values=  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = [619, 101, 815, 1361, 178]
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.bar(a, values)
plt.show()
```

[image: The result of the code]

Comment: Maybe you meant `plt.bar(values, a)`? To really use `[619, 101, 815, 1361, 178]` as the xaxis, you should set a width (the default is 1), or set an edge color: `plt.bar(a, values, ec='r')`. The default bars are too narrow to see. Adding an edge forces them to be visible as at least one line. The width of the bar (default 1) is measured in the units of the x-axis.

Comment: @JohanC No actually, i want the values on the y and a on the x

Comment: @JohanC - is the default 1 or 0.8? The docs say the latter, not that it really makes a difference.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, sorry, 0.8.  Certainly too narrow in this case.  `plt.bar(a, values, width=40)` could work here.

Comment: Completely agree, certainly too narrow.

Answer (score 1):

The bar width is set to a default value of `0.8` so when your x-axis has such a large range, the bars are so skinny that they disappear.

The reason for the `0.8` is that bar charts are typically used for labelled categories, which are effectively spaced by `1` along the x-axis.

So you can set the width directly.  (It's also possible to calculate a width, to make this more automatic, but then you need to decide about overlaps, etc.)

[image]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
plt.xlim(0, 1450)
plt.bar(a, values, width = 50)
```

It seems your data might be better suited for a horizontal bar plot (but don't take this too seriously as it may not have the right meaning at all), and if you want horizontal bars, you can do so like this:

[image]

```
plt.barh(values, a)
```